# Jest, env preset and stage-0 features

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

i am trying to configure jest, but face the fact it can't handle es6 features.

To fix this I have added configuration to package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "./node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
}
```

My .babelrc config:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2017",
    "stage-0",
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
      },
      "spec": true,
      "modules": false,
      "debug": true
    }],
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
  ]
}
```

It look proper to me, but jest anyway fail to run with `Test suite failed to run` on `import React from 'react';` and on props in

```
class App extends Component {
   static propTypes = {}
}
```

At the moment I have no idea what have go  wrong, but it look like that stage-x features not only not availabale in env preset, but `plugins` and other presets are ignored. 
But webpack build bundle without any errors.
So look like it's jest problem.

May help me find out what's going on, please?

==========
fixed config `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "es2016",
    "es2017",
    "stage-0",
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
      },
      "spec": true,
      "modules": false,
      "debug": true
    }],
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
  ]
}
```

and `package.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "config.env": "<rootDir>/config/application.production.js",
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|po)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "^.+\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "js",
      "json"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `es2017` preset doesn't include `es2016` and `es2015`.
You can either include all of them explicitly, or use [preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) instead.

Also, you don't have to explicitly set the `transform` property in the jest configuration.

[from Jest documentation:](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html)

> Note: babel-jest is automatically installed when installing Jest and will automatically transform files if a babel configuration exists in your project.

Comment: Well, I have removed it, but jest still fail on `import React from 'react';`

Comment: silly me, how did i miss it.. you should use [preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) because `es2017` doesn't include `es2016` and `es2015`. i'll fix the answer

Comment: But actually I have `preset-env` in config above…
But look like you are right, I have changed config to [package.json] and [.babelrc] above. I have putt them into original post, because they don't fit comment size.

But I have feeling that my .babelrc are kinda strange at the moment.